# CSS huge grid problems

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

I'm using CSS grid for a timeline. The grid is yielding about 1300 divs, which is really bad for performance.

I need to have each of these cells to be clickable and show a different color on hover. I cannot find any way to style "empty" nodes or interact with them without rendering all of those 1300 divs.

What can I do?

[image: So many divs!!!!]

Comment: use JS and coordinate to know where you are in the grid

Comment: Why do you need 1300 divs? Just use one master div with a properly repeating background image to show your "grid", and then use Javascript to determine where someone clicked in your div. Then create a "highlighting" div *only* for the region you know the user meant to highlight, with CSS width/height sizing it to fit your grid, and CSS top/left positioning to ensure it's in the correct spot relative to your master div.

Comment: You also might be able to do something like this using D3.

Comment: Maybe you can include your code for the grids. For the different color thing you need javascript to come up with a random hex value and then use an event handler to change the color of the hovered cell.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I solved this by using repeating background and dynamic inject elements on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as  [Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans)
 suggested, the best way would be detect mouse click and add item dynamically. You can customize the width and height of items by assigning values to `item_width` and `item_height`.

```js
var item_width=40;
var item_height=40;
var added_items=[];
$(function(){
      $('.grid').on('click', function(e){
      var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
      var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top; 
      var item=$('<div class="item"></div>');
      var left=Math.floor(x/item_width)*item_width;
      var top=Math.floor(y/item_height)*item_height;
      var position={ 'left':left, 'top':top };
      var index=added_items.findIndex(p => p.left == position.left && p.top == position.top);
      if(index<0){
      added_items.push(position);
      item.css('left', left);
      item.css('top', top);
      item.css('background', "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16))
      item.appendTo($('.grid'));
      }
    });
  
});
```

```css
.grid {
  
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
  margin:10px;
}
.item {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  position:absolute;
  background:red;  
}
.item:hover { 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid"> </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add your columns classes a eventHandler and same classes act same hover or click.. 
Also 1300 divs are really decreace your page's performance. For that you can research for infinite scroll or like that methods.

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/endless-scrolling-local