# Edges of a CSS grid cannot be scrolled to

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

Basically, I have this user-customisable CSS-grid (node: width and height don't have limits, and I do not want it to have such) and it can be really really wide and/or really really high, and if that happens, the scrolling just stops somewhere and the elements not in the middle of the grid just get made inaccessible.

This is what I have at the moment and I got zero idea how to make it scroll to all parts of the grid

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
#board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 26px
}
.tile {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center
}
```

```html
<div id="game_div">
    <div id="board">
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <div class="tile"></div>
        <!--
        There are a lot more tiles that get added via .appendChild().
        Imagine like a few thousand more tiles here.
        -->
    </div>
    <!-- Irrelevant Minesweeper stuff -->
    <button onclick="help()">Stuck?</button>
    <p id="minecount" style="display:inline"></p>
</div>
```

PS: Before anyone links me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65855499/cannot-scroll-to-the-end-of-left-edge-in-horizontal-scroll-css), I have tried to understand it and it hasn't worked, so I am asking more specifically. (also [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920274/css-huge-grid-problems) as well)

EDIT: Thank you Teemu, I had to add `flex-wrap: wrap` to the body ruleset

Comment: I;ve create a snippet from your code. Coul you please [edit] it to make a [mre]?

Comment: Don't make `body` flexible, create a flexible wrapper instead.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? And how many tiles do there have to be before you start seeing a problem?

Comment: @AHaworth some dude on discord told me to do that so it would center on screen correctly